# Angular 6 Material - Autocomplete with data from server

Tags: angular, autocomplete, angular-material

I need to fetch some data from a server and show it into the Material autocomplete.

The thing is that when you click in the input field, you can't have the results right away. You have to type something into the input field to get some results back.

I've forked and changed the autocomplete demo on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qnxr7z?file=app/autocomplete-overview-example.ts), so you can see what I'm talking about. In this demo, I didn't actually fetch data from a server. I just mocked it with some setTimeout. But the behavior is pretty much the same.

HTML:

```
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
<input matInput placeholder="State" aria-label="State" [matAutocomplete]="auto" [formControl]="stateCtrl">
<mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
  <mat-option *ngFor="let state of filteredStates | async" [value]="state.name">
    <img style="vertical-align:middle;" aria-hidden src="{{state.flag}}" height="25" />
    <span>{{ state.name }}</span> |
    <small>Population: {{state.population}}</small>
  </mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>
```

TS:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {FormControl} from '@angular/forms';

import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {map, startWith} from 'rxjs/operators';

export class State {
  constructor(public name: string, public population: string, public flag: string) { }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'autocomplete-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'autocomplete-overview-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['autocomplete-overview-example.css']
})
export class AutocompleteOverviewExample implements OnInit {
  stateCtrl: FormControl;
  filteredStates: Observable<any[]>;

  states: State[];

  constructor() {
    this.stateCtrl = new FormControl();
    this.filteredStates = this.stateCtrl.valueChanges
      .pipe(
        startWith(''),
        map(state => state ? this.filterStates(state) : this.states)
      );
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      return this.states  = [
    {
      name: 'Arkansas',
      population: '2.978M',
      // https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Flag_of_Arkansas.svg
      flag: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9d/Flag_of_Arkansas.svg'
    },
    {
      name: 'California',
      population: '39.14M',
      // https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Flag_of_California.svg
      flag: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/01/Flag_of_California.svg'
    },
    {
      name: 'Florida',
      population: '20.27M',
      // https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Flag_of_Florida.svg
      flag: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f7/Flag_of_Florida.svg'
    },
    {
      name: 'Texas',
      population: '27.47M',
      // https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Flag_of_Texas.svg
      flag: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f7/Flag_of_Texas.svg'
    }
  ];
    }, 1000);
  }

  filterStates(name: string) {
    return this.states.filter(state =>
      state.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(name.toLowerCase()) === 0);
  }

}
```

P.S: I've done my searches and researches :) I've found results that are somewhat similar to my question, but the details are completely different and they are NOT what I'm looking for. So I had to ask this question separately.

Comment: You need to add filter(to check if the user have entered at least 2 or 3 characters, then a debounce so that you can send the request to backend only when the user has stopped typing for few milisecs. These two needs to be added in the beginning of the pipe.

Comment: You see, I don't want a debounce. I just want when the user enters the input field, right away the autocomplete fetches the data from a server and shows it.
Then for the searching part, you're absolutely right. I can add a filter and a debounce to control the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is with `filteredStates` initially you are not assigning any value in it. Check the modified code below:

```
constructor() {
    this.stateCtrl = new FormControl();
    this.stateCtrl.valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
      this.filterStates(val);
    });
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.states  = [
        {
          name: 'Arkansas',
          population: '2.978M',
          flag: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9d/Flag_of_Arkansas.svg'
        },
        {
          name: 'California',
          population: '39.14M',
          flag: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/01/Flag_of_California.svg'
        },
        {
          name: 'Florida',
          population: '20.27M',
          flag: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f7/Flag_of_Florida.svg'
        },
        {
          name: 'Texas',
          population: '27.47M',
          flag: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f7/Flag_of_Texas.svg'
        }
    ];
    this.filteredStates = new Observable(observer => {
      setTimeout(() => {
          observer.next(this.states);
      }, 1000);
    });
}

filterStates(name: string) {
    let filteredData = this.states.filter(state =>
    state.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(name.toLowerCase()) === 0);
    this.filteredStates = new Observable(observer => {
        observer.next(filteredData);
    }); 
}
```

Comment: I replaced your modified code in my StackBlitz and everything works at the beginning. But the filtering doesn't work anymore.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qnxr7z?file=app/autocomplete-overview-example.ts

Comment: BTW, in your code, imagine that there is a server. So, first you've got the results (states) from the server, and then you've faked a second with setTimeout and then you've sent the results back to autocomplete.
Now, what if it's a real server?
I don't know how much time should I fake with setTimeout in order to send the results back to autocomplete.

Comment: this setTimeout is only for local data, when you get data from service there is no need of it.